# Enable Cell editing kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I was ashame to post this kind of question but I'm desperate. I am new to kendo, and I simple to make my grid editable. 
here's my code

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Server.Models.MasterFoo>()
        .Name("gridRules")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:300px; margin: 0px" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c)
                .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' />")
                .Width(24);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ID)
                .Hidden(true);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Description)
                .EditorTemplateName("Descriptions")
                .Title("SpecialDescription");
        })
        .DataSource(ds => ds
            .Ajax()
            .Model(m =>
            {
                m.Id(f => f.ID);
                m.Field(f => f.Name).Editable(true);
                m.Field(f => f.Description).Editable(true);
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetFooBar", "MyController", new { area = "Administration" })
                .Data("foo.param"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateFoo", "MyController", new { area = "Administration" })
                .Data("foo.param"))
            .Batch(true)
        )
        .Events(events => events
            .SaveChanges("foo.gridChanged")
            //.Edit("foo.gridChanges")
            //.Change("foo.gridSelection")
            .DataBound("foo.gridDataBound")
        )
        .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
        .Scrollable()
        .Navigatable()
        //.Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
        //.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))     
    )
```

Now i'm having a problem:  I can't edit my grid. 
And if I add //.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) it doesn't work at all. Im using Kendo Q2 2013, what do I missed?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATES** Here's what happen whenever I enabled `Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))`
[image]

Comment: all you need to do is add in the following into your columns collection: `columns.Command(c => c.Edit());` this will enable the edit button for you.

Comment: what I want is to edit it directly on the cell, I do have a tool bar button that include save button  and will verify the changes and save all the valid changes

Answer (score 0):

This code is good :

```
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
```

But your also need the save button in toolbar :

```
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Save();
            })
```

Extract from the kendo documentation :

> - Turn on the inline cell editing by setting: .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) Enable the Add New Record, Save
>     Changes and Discard Changes buttons on the toolbar by setting:
>     .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create(); toolbar.Save(); }
> - Set .Batch(true) and .ServerOperation(false) properties in the DataSource declaration to enable batch updates and perform the paging,
>     sorting, filtering and grouping operations on the client.
> - Invoke the CRUD action methods in the DataSource

Comment: whenever I add .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) my cell turns. My program broke. and my text turns into green

Answer (score 0):

Find out that I simply need to add parameter-less constructor in my model.

```
public class MasterFoo {
     public MasterFoo() {}
}
```

Here's the lessons that I learned:

1. The Kendo UI grid was bound to model and it instantiates an instance of it upon adding some properties/attributes like editable and Filterables
2. Never ignore error message
3. And the most important is Don't commit suicide if can't resolve your bug. Try ask community, and if still nothing, go home and have some sleep.